# Prefetching related objects for templates

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `Signup` and `Report`, related via a third model, `Training`:

```py
class Signup(models.Model):
    pilot = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signups"
    )
    training = models.ForeignKey(
        Training, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signups"
    )

class Report(models.Model):
    training = models.OneToOneField(
        "trainings.Training", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True
    )
```

And e.g. in the update view for a `Report` I try to prefetch the `Signup`s and their `Pilot`s and sort them into the context:

```py
class ReportUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Report

    def get_object(self):
        training = get_object_or_404(Training, date=self.kwargs["date"])
        report = get_object_or_404(
            Report.objects.select_related("training")
            .prefetch_related("training__signups__pilot")
            training=training,
        )
        return report

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        runs_by_signup = {}
        for signup in self.object.training.selected_signups:
            runs_by_signup[signup] = [...]
        context["runs_by_signup"] = runs_by_signup
        return context
```

and in the corresponding template I call `signup.pilot` like so:

```html
{% for signup, runs in runs_by_signup.items %}
<tr>
    <td class="text-nowrap">{{ signup.pilot }}
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, each `signup.pilot` results in a call to the database to figure out the corresponding `pilot`. Is there a way to avoid these extra calls or do I have to store all information in `get_context_data`?

Comment: Replace the `prefetch` to this `prefetch_related("training__pilot")`. Also why you iterating `selected_singups` in `get_context` ? Why can't you do `values` there

Comment: `Training` does not have `pilot`, so prefetching it results in an error. `Training.selected_signups` is a subset of `Training.signups`, there are also e.g. cancelled and waiting `Signup`s.

Comment: Can you share more detailed code? How was `selected_signups` built and how is it processed exactly in the for loop?

Comment: You can find `selected_signups` at https://github.com/germannp/acbeo.ch/blob/main/trainings/models.py#L43 and the processing loop at https://github.com/germannp/acbeo.ch/blob/main/bookkeeping/views.py#L323.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe **avoid the extra calls** to the database by using `prefetch_related` in the `get_context_data()` method.

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ...
    runs_by_signup = {}
    for signup in self.object.training.selected_signups.prefetch_related("pilot"):
        runs_by_signup[signup] = [...]
    context["runs_by_signup"] = runs_by_signup
    return context
```

This will prefetch the `pilot` for all of the Signups in the `runs_by_signup` dict. So, when you access the `pilot` field, it will **not result** in an extra call to the database.

Comment: Since `selected_signups` is currently not a `queryset` I have to use `prefetch_related_objects` to keep the calls constant. Thank you! 